# Not getting the complete result of selected records with single quotes inside IN operator

Tags: c#, sql

I have the below code:

```
List<string> queryEventIDList=new List<string>();//added new list<string>
foreach (ListItem lstAssign in lstEvent.Items)
{
    if (lstAssign.Selected == true)
    {
        queryEventIDList.Add(lstAssign.Value);
        logfield = logfield + "," + lstEvent.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
string queryEventIDs = string.Join(",", queryEventIDList.ToArray());
```

From queryEventIDs, I am getting the selected values. I have a below mentioned query line in where condition. Suppose I am selecting A and B,it gives me the result of only A.

```
" (('" + queryEventIDs + "'='') OR (inq1.event_id in('" + queryEventIDs + "'))) AND  " +  //queryeventids(A,B)//skips result of B
```

So I slightly modified that line. I removed single quotes('') from it.

```
" (('" + queryEventIDs + "'='') OR (inq1.event_id in(" + queryEventIDs + "))) AND  " +  //Queryeventids(A,B)//gives both result
```

So this gave me the both selected results of A and B. This is strange. What is the difference for `inq1.event_id in('" + queryEventIDs + "'` with and without single quotes?

I am a beginner in C#.

Comment: With single quotes, you get the query: `...in('1,2,3')`, when what you's want is: `...in('1', '2', '3')`

Comment: while debugging,i am getting the the actual valuue of queryeventids as "A,B".So how it will take inside IN?

Comment: @HoneyBadger..yes...right now,it is taking only A inside IN and skipping B

Comment: @HoneyBadger...Do u have any idea regarding this issue?then pls let me knw...

Comment: Thank u @HoneyBadger...your comment has given me some idea to sort out this issue...:)

Comment: Glad you managed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Replace` solved my issue

```
" (('" + queryEventIDs + "'='') OR (inq1.event_id in('" + queryEventIDs.Replace(",", "','") + "'))) AND  " +
```